# Кривая по точкам

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите каким образом построить ГЛАДКУЮ кривую по заданным точкам?

Пробовал QPainterPath::quadTo(), но кривая не достаточно гладкая, в силу того, что она проходит через каждую точку. Как добиться большой гладкости? кол-во точек в пределах 100 штук, чем больше тем точнее, длина кривой может быть как несколько пикселей, так и несколько сотен пикселей.

За основу построения кривой был взят алгоритм [отсюда](https://www.toptal.com/c-plus-plus/rounded-corners-bezier-curves-qpainter)

[image: Использование quadTo()]

Грубо говоря нужно чтобы кривая описывала поведения, но не обязательно проходила через каждую точку, вот пример от руки нарисовал:

[image: Пример]

UPD1:
Гладкость нарушается при переводе из дробных координат в целые пиксели. На картинке я выделил точки некоторые участки где нарушена гладкость. Таким образом я и подумал, что нужно чтобы кривая не обязательно проходила через точку.
Построение происходит от точки к точке через quadTo(), используя алгоритм приведенный по ссылке.

[image: Пример]

UPD2:

Вот пример набора точек по которым строится кривая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В зависимости от решаемой физической задачи и природы исходных данных, возможно, вам подойдут: скользящее среднее (разных типов), сглаженные сплайны, аппроксимация полиномомами, подгонка параметров физической модели (минимизация суммы отклонений от экспериментальных данных), кластеризация+отбрасывание выколотых точек ....

Comment: В данном конкретном случае, это построение ортодромии по точкам, которые заданы в виде географических координат, в радианах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно точно сформулировать критерии. Если проходить не обязана, то сглаживающие сплайны подойдут, но они могут вообще ни через одну точку не пройти.

Вообще сплайны обычно обеспечивают гладкость сопряжения участков кривой - соседние сплайны согласованы по значению (неразрывность), по наклону (гладкость первого порядка), возможно - по кривизне - гладкость второго порядка

Раз точек слишком много, то полилинию можно в начале упростить  с помощью алгоритма [Дугласа-Пекера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0), потом через оставшиеся точки провести плавную кривую

[Вот один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691499/how-do-i-draw-a-closed-curve-over-a-set-of-points) из простых (с минимумом расчётов) методов построения гладко сопряжённых кубических кривых Безье

---

С учётом добавлений:

Даны две точки на поверхности сферы, между ними нужно нарисовать ортодромию, дугу большого круга.

Промежуточные точки этой дуги можно рассчитать с нужным шагом с помощью геобиблиотек или с использованием простых формул [отсюда](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (раздел bearing-intermediate point). Ортодромия при изображении в любой проекции будет плавной, поэтому много точек не нужно.

Полученные точки (lat/lon) нужно перевести в пространство отображаемой карты (x,y)

Через полученные точки на плоскости нужно провести плавную кривую. Можно воспользоваться вышеописанным методом для кубических кривых или упомянутым автором методом для квадратичных - но только в том случае, если он обеспечивает плавное сопряжение, чего я навскидку не увидел.

Рассчитанные кривые отрисовываются с помощью графических примитивов (для кубических это `cubicTo`)

Comment: на самом деле кол-во точек я могу варьировать, хоть 1 сделать, тогда это будет просто прямая. Эти точки - координаты на карте, которую можно маштабировать, соответвественно при большом увеличении и малом кол-ве точек, кривая может следовать по ложному пути, в данный момент я эмпиричиским путем пытаюсь подогнать кол-во контрольных точек под каждый зум, но пока без успешно. Нужно чтобы и кривая гладкая была и максимальное соответствие истинным координатам было

Comment: @ipkis Если речь идёт об ортодромии, то не вполне ясно, откуда куча точек -  она задаётся двумя крайними точками, а остальные можно рассчитать с нужным шагом

Comment: Ну про это я и говорю, что шаг (кол-во результирующий точек) я могу менять, но две крайние точки задаются пользователем, с помощью щелчка мыши, и получается что шаг нужно адаптировать под каждую конкретную ортодромию...

Comment: Так промежуточные точки Вы умеете рассчитывать?

Comment: да есть функция для расчета контрольных точек

Comment: ОК, тогда посмотрите обновление ответа

Answer (score 0):

Если вы пишете программу под Windows, то там есть встроенная поддержка сплайнов и кривых Безье. Сплайны: [DrawCurve](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawcurve), кривые Безье: [Bezier Splines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-bezier-splines-about), метод [DrawBeziers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawbeziers).

Answer (score -1):

Зачем что-то изобретать когда [qt умеет рисовать сглаженные граффики.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-splinechart-example.html)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уменьшайте количество точек в апроксимированном наборе и получится аккуратная кривая. Там же есть поддержка Antialiasing.